# how to call a method if a switch is get on in xcode in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just apply a switch on my `viewcontroller` and I define a method to get called when the switch is get on

```
-(void)switchIsChanged:(UISwitch *)paramsender{
    if ([paramsender isOn]) {
      UIAlertController *alertView = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Are you sure" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];   
        [alertView addAction:defaultAction];
        [self presentViewController:alertView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
```

this is the method but I just want to call this whole alert thing in a method. How can I do it?

Comment: why are you doing like that?

Comment: i am just practicing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this ::

```
UISwitch *swi; //however you get your switch, as a storyboard component or initialized in your code
[swi addTarget:self action:@selector(switchIsChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```